# ansible tower - append custom host variables

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower

Within ansible tower inventory, I need to programmatically append custom variables to specific hosts rather than enter them manually. How can I do this? Do any modules exist for this?

Answer (score 1):

One can use tower-cli or tower api.  Where as I found tower-clis quite useful.
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/towerapi/tower_cli.html